# Select all data from two mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I this codes to join two tables in my database. It didn't show any error message when trying to echo it using while loop, but also it shows nothing. Can anyone help me please?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usr_details, paymnt_details WHERE usr_details.Trnsnubr = paymnt_details.Trnsnubr";

$sql = 
"SELECT *
FROM usr_details 
JOIN paymnt_details ON usr_details.Trnsnubr = paymnt_details.Trnsnubr";
```

This is my html and PHP code for echoing:

```
$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
<table width="100%" height="109" border="1" cellpadding="2px" >
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5" class="mainheader">Registerd Persons</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="16"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="tableheader" width="68">Payment</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="64">Amount</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="58">Date</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="74">Trnsnubr</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="97"> Paymenttyp </td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="59">Room Type</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="96"> Packgname </td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="142">Full name</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="1"> Email </td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="1">Mobile </td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="1">Address</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="1">Country</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="40">Mem_num</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="40">Chptr</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="40">Ral</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="40">ex-mem-1-name</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="40">ex-mem-2-name</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="40">Faly-mem-1-name</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="40">Faly-mem-2-name</td>
    </tr>
<?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 
$amount=$row["amount"];
$successness=$row["successness"];
$Timestamp=$row["Timestamp"];
$fname=$row["fname"];
$lname=$row["lname"];
$memnumbr=$row["memnumbr"];
$chptrpostion=$row["chptrpostion"];
$ralpositin=$row["ralpositin"];
$adrs1=$row["adrs1"];
$adrs2=$row["adrs2"];
$city=$row["city"];
$cntry=$row["cntry"];
$MTelNo=$row["MTelNo"];
$email=$row["email"];
$Trnsnubr=$row["Trnsnubr"];
$packgname=$row["packgname"];
$rtype=$row["rtype"];
$paymenttyp=$row["paymenttyp"];
$exmem1name=$row["exmem1name"];
$exmem2name=$row["exmem2name"];
$familymem1name=$row["familymem1name"];
$familymem2name=$row["familymem2name"];


        ?> 
<tr>
<td>  dfgdfgfdgdfgdg<?php echo $successness;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $amount;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $Timestamp;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $Trnsnubr;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $paymenttyp;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $rtype;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $packgname;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $fname." ".$lname;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $email;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $MTelNo;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $adrs1." ".$adrs2." ".$city;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $cntry;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $memnumbr;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $chptrpostion;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $ralpositin;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $exmem1name;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $exmem2name;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $familymem1name;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $familymem2name;?></td>
</tr>
<?php 
}; 
?> 
</table>
```

This is my whole coding file:

```
<?php session_start();
$user_name = $_SESSION['username'];
$user_pass = $_SESSION['password'];
if ( $user_name == '' ) {
header('location:login.php');
exit();
 }
?>
<?php require_once('connection.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('function.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="css/users.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="../dojo/dojo/resources/dojo.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="../dojo/dijit/themes/nihilo/nihilo.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dojo/dojo/dojo.js" ></script>
<script src="js/navigation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
<style type="text/css">
.tableheader {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #96C;
}
.mainheader {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #09F;
}
</style></head>

<body class="nihilo">
<span class="tableheader"></span>
<div id="wrap">
<!-- Enable when Ajax is loading -->
<div id="loading_wrap"></div>
<div id="loading"><img src="images/loading.gif" width="32" height="32" alt="loading" /><br />Loading...</div>
<!-- End loading  -->
  <div id="head">
    <div id="subHead"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$limit= 5;
$start_from = ($page-1) * $limit; 
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM usr_details ORDER BY Trnsnubr ASC LIMIT $start_from, $limit "; 
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM usr_details, paymnt_details WHERE usr_details.Trnsnubr = paymnt_details.Trnsnubr";
/*$sql = 
"SELECT *
FROM usr_details 
JOIN paymnt_details ON usr_details.Trnsnubr = paymnt_details.Trnsnubr";*/
$sql = "SELECT usr_details.*, paymnt_details.amount, paymnt_details.successness
FROM usr_details 
JOIN paymnt_details ON usr_details.Trnsnubr = paymnt_details.Trnsnubr";
$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
?> 
<table width="100%" height="109" border="1" cellpadding="2px" >
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5" class="mainheader">Registerd Persons</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="16"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="tableheader" width="68">Payment</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="64">Amount</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="58">Date</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="74">Trnsnubr</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="97"> Paymenttyp </td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="59">Room Type</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="96"> Packgname </td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="142">Full name</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="1"> Email </td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="1">Mobile </td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="1">Address</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="1">Country</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="40">Mem_num</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="40">Chptr</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="40">Ral</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="40">ex-mem-1-name</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="40">ex-mem-2-name</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="40">Faly-mem-1-name</td>
    <td class="tableheader" width="40">Faly-mem-2-name</td>
    </tr>
<?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 
$amount=$row["amount"];
$successness=$row["successness"];
$Timestamp=$row["Timestamp"];
$fname=$row["fname"];
$lname=$row["lname"];
$memnumbr=$row["memnumbr"];
$chptrpostion=$row["chptrpostion"];
$ralpositin=$row["ralpositin"];
$adrs1=$row["adrs1"];
$adrs2=$row["adrs2"];
$city=$row["city"];
$cntry=$row["cntry"];
$MTelNo=$row["MTelNo"];
$email=$row["email"];
$Trnsnubr=$row["Trnsnubr"];
$packgname=$row["packgname"];
$rtype=$row["rtype"];
$paymenttyp=$row["paymenttyp"];
$exmem1name=$row["exmem1name"];
$exmem2name=$row["exmem2name"];
$familymem1name=$row["familymem1name"];
$familymem2name=$row["familymem2name"];
?> 
<tr>
<td> <?php echo $successness;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $amount;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $Timestamp;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $Trnsnubr;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $paymenttyp;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $rtype;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $packgname;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $fname." ".$lname;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $email;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $MTelNo;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $adrs1." ".$adrs2." ".$city;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $cntry;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $memnumbr;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $chptrpostion;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $ralpositin;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $exmem1name;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $exmem2name;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $familymem1name;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $familymem2name;?></td>
</tr>
<?php 
}; 
?> 
</table>

</div>
 <div id="footer">
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
 </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you show them outside the loop? Please, provide more significant code

Comment: There is no apparent reason that no data would be returned a priori, so either the `usr_details.Trnsnubr = paymnt_details.Trnsnubr` condition isn't met or you aren't displaying the data correctly.

Comment: my table names are 1. usr_details 2. paymnt_details
and i'm trying to echo those values into html table using while loop, i tried it using one table data and there is no problems

Comment: Can we see the code for the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these tables have columns with the same name this request will cause an error. It's happens coz you tried get all values by column name. try to not use * in difficult queries.

Try do like this:

```
SELECT usr_details.*, paymnt_details.field1, paymnt_details.field2
FROM usr_details 
JOIN paymnt_details ON usr_details.Trnsnubr = paymnt_details.Trnsnubr
```

1

```
<?
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usr_details LIMIT 1");
var_dump(  mysql_fetch_assoc($res) );
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM paymnt_details LIMIT 1");
var_dump(  mysql_fetch_assoc($res) );
$sql = "SELECT usr_details.* FROM usr_details LEFT JOIN paymnt_details ON usr_details.Trnsnubr = paymnt_details.Trnsnubr";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
var_dump($res);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
var_dump( mysql_error() );
?>
```

Comment: i uploaded whole file... if you can please give me a help sir... 
thank you

Comment: is this ok to use above code like this?
$sql = 

"SELECT *
FROM usr_details 
JOIN paymnt_details ON usr_details.Trnsnubr = paymnt_details.Trnsnubr";

Comment: you must replace field1 and field2 by your columns names for my example. in your query from comment you have column name Trnsnubr in 2 tables, so you cant use `SELECT *`.

Comment: I tried this also.... but nothing happened sir...... don't know why... 
$sql = "SELECT usr_details.*, paymnt_details.amount, paymnt_details.successness
FROM usr_details 
JOIN paymnt_details ON usr_details.Trnsnubr = paymnt_details.Trnsnubr";
$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Try do `var_dump($rs_result);` and `var_dump( mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result) );`. Write what will happen.

Comment: sir i don't know much about var_dump so i put these codes like this

$sql = "SELECT usr_details.*, paymnt_details.amount, paymnt_details.successness
FROM usr_details 
JOIN paymnt_details ON usr_details.Trnsnubr = paymnt_details.Trnsnubr";
$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
var_dump($rs_result);

while ($row= var_dump( mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result) )) {


and when i run this i got a error message saying 

resource(7) of type (mysql result) bool(false)

Comment: ok, the first var_dump in right place, and sql query executed, its good. i put some code on answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11703/discussion-between-shaad-and-yasitha)

Comment: i put 

while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result) )) {
    var_dump($row); 

it gives me a error 

syntax error, unexpected ')' on line 96

line 96 is 
while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result) )) {

Comment: Thank you all error was gone and it working well now... special thanks goes to Mr. ShaaD Hats-Off...